# RelativeLayout Three Buttons Centered Above TextViews

Tags: android, button, alignment, textview

So in my layout, I've got three buttons on the same line, one left, center and right aligned. I also have TextViews below the buttons to serve as labels, but they too are aligned left, center and right respectively. I'd like them to instead be centered below the buttons and on the same line as one another, but I can't figure out how to do this without explicitly setting coordinates, which will then break on some phones. I tried setting various weights and layout options, but it just doesn't work how I'd like. Is there a way to do this in a RelativeLayout? Or maybe it's just not possible. Finally, I've got more three TextViews on the same line and one button on the bottom. I would like to align as shown bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3nba.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean, would you be able to draw a picture of what you want? :)

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly your problem is. I see what you want, but can you take a screenshot of your UI designer so we can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You can't center one element below another with RelativeLayout.  You could try a horizontal LinearLayout with three RelativeLayouts (one for each column).  You could contain the whole thing in a vertical LinearLayout to get the bottom button.

TableLayout or GridLayout are possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

As people suggested, there is no way to center a `View` below another `View` in `RelativeLayout`. You could maybe use this hack if you can confirm that the `TextView` width need not be more the `Button` width. The solution is: you make the `TextView` align its left and right edge to the `Button` above. Then set the gravity of the `TextView` to `center` so that the text inside `TextView` is centered.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Txt1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Txt2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Txt3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```